# Need .htaccess rewrite rule after site update changed database url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I recently updates some software on my site and the urls to reference the database have changed. I need to create a rewrite rule to forward the old database links to their new url. I've tried for quite awhile with no luck and decided that after my last attempt at a rule completely errored out the entire site I would come ask for some help.

The trialing "X" below is a variable.

Old url:

```
http://www.mysite.com/downloads/index.php?do=listings&catid=X
```

needs to be forward to new url:

```
http://www.mysite.com/downloads/index.php?categoryid=X
```

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I've tried many variations of this `RewriteRule ^downloads\/index\.php\?do=listings&catid=/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.mysite\.com\/downloads\/index\.php\?categoryid=$1" [R=301, L]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^do=listing&catid=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/?downloads/(index\.php)?$ /downloads/index.php?categoryid=%1 [L,R=301]
```

Or, if you need to put it in the **downloads** directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /downloads/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^do=listing&catid=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ index.php?categoryid=%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Tried both but neither worked for me. Url did not rewrite at all.

Comment: Figured out the issue. You stated "listing" in the query string when it should of been "listings". Thanks.